# Get Swift Playgrounds back? iOS 10 GM Warning

Tags: ios, swift

I just updated to the final release of iOS 10.0.1 on iPad Pro 12.9 inch

Swift Playgrounds is gone, and it's not in the App Store.

I've lost all my Playgrounds, I presume. No great loss.

But how do I get Swift Playgrounds back?

and... how do I warn other Swift Playground users about this?

Comment: It is a beta, and data loss may happen. Wait until the public release of iOS 10 and Swift Playgrounds.

Comment: It's no longer in Beta. Full release of iOS 10 is now available (some countries), Playgrounds is not there.

Comment: no, it's still in beta. The public release is September 13.

Comment: What date do you think it is in parts of the world on the other side of the date line?

Comment: that would be the 12th...

Comment: Ok... but why have I been able to update to 10.0.1 today?

Comment: that's still a beta.